# Using UIDropInteractionDelegate and movies

Tags: swift, video

Im trying to implement drag and drop photos and videos into my app.

I have made photos work using below code

```
public func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return session.hasItemsConforming(toTypeIdentifiers:
        [kUTTypeImage as String, kUTTypeMovie as String]) &&
        session.items.count == 1
}

public func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate
    session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {

    let dropOperation: UIDropOperation?

    if session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
        //Make sure over drop space
    }
    else
    {
        dropOperation = .forbidden
    }

    return UIDropProposal(operation: dropOperation!)
}

public func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction,
                            performDrop session: UIDropSession) {

    if session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
        session.loadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (items) in
            if let images = items as? [UIImage] {
                //Do something with the image file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I said photos work perfectly but im unsure what to do about videos (kUTTypeMovie), 
what class type is videos in "session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self)"

Thanks

Comment: Just for anyone googling here, the syntax for the identifiers has annoyingly change. See answer 2022

Answer (score 4):

You can get an URL to the movie file using the `itemProviders` `loadFileRepresentation` like this

```
for item in session.items {
    if item.itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeMovie as String) {
        item.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeMovie as String) { (url, error) in
                
             // Copy the file to your documents directory before using it
            
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to also add kuTTypeMovie to the `canHandle` function

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return session.hasItemsConforming(toTypeIdentifiers: [kUTTypeMovie as String])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add onto @torof's solution i finished the copy part to which he refers in the comment in his code. As file destination i use `.cachesDirectory` since i don't want to permanently store the file, but rather just for a use in this session, just outside of the callback. This way it gets cleaned up by the OS automatically when space is needed.

```swift
session.items.filter { $0.itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.movie.identifier) }.forEach { item in
    item.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier) { [weak self] (videoURL, error) in
        guard let url = videoURL,
              let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
        let destURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)

        try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: destURL)
        
        // the file is now at destURL
        // you may us it now outside of the callback
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

##### 2022 ... syntax for type identifiers has changed:

```
func dropInteraction(_ i: UIDropInteraction, canHandle s: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    guard s.items.count == 1 else { return false }
    return s.hasItemsConforming(
     toTypeIdentifiers: [UTType.image.identifier, UTType.video.identifier])
}
```

and you need:

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
```