# UIDropInteractionDelegate handling videos

Tags: ios, swift

I'm implementing a DropInteraction on a view which should handle images and video from the photos app. I implmented the `UIDropInteractionDelegate` on my ViewController and it works perfectly fine.

Handling images worked instantly but i am struggling to read the videos.

```swift
// handling images
session.loadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self) { [weak self] imageItems in
...
}
```

I've tried all [NSItemProviderReading](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemproviderreading) Conforming Types in the `loadObjects` as `ofClass` but none seems to work with videos. How should those be handled?

`AVURLAsset` or `NSURL` seemed promising but did not work :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977855/dropdelegate-safari-drag-image check out this one. Have you tried listening to all the audio and video types of the `UTType` [mentioned over here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/system_declared_uniform_type_identifiers#overview)?

Comment: Solved at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894917/using-uidropinteractiondelegate-and-movies/72880962#72880962